# How to create complex multi model join query set with Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

I want to create a query set with multiple tables. I cannot find any resource that helps
Beside some small 2 table join examples, I cannot find any resource that is helpful for this, not in stackoverflow, the Django docs or even in the ORM Cookbook.
Below is firstly the SQL I want to recreate followed by the models classes, simplified for the purpose of this question. They have in fact a LOT more fields.

```
SELECT  doc_uid, 
         docd_filename, 
         doct_name, 
         docd_media_url
  FROM   vugd_detail,
         vug_virtual_user_group,
         vugdoc_vug_docs,
         doc_documents,
         docd_detail,
         doct_type
  WHERE  vugd_vug_uid = vug_uid
  AND    vugdoc_vug_uid = vug_uid
  AND    vugdoc_doc_uid = doc_uid
  AND    docd_doc_uid = doc_uid
  AND    doct_uid = doc_doct_uid
  AND    vugd_status = 1
  AND    docd_status = 1
  AND    NOW() BETWEEN vugd_start_date AND vugd_end_date
  AND    NOW() BETWEEN docd_start_date AND docd_end_date
  AND    vug_uid = {{Some ID}}; 
  

class VugVirtualUserGroup(models.Model):
    objects = None
    vug_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vug_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    vug_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    vug_created_on = models.DateTimeField()
    vug_created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vug_virtual_user_group'
        app_label = 'main'
        
class VugdDetail(models.Model):
    objects = None
    vugd_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vugd_vug_uid = models.ForeignKey(VugVirtualUserGroup, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vugd_vug_uid')
    vugd_long_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vugd_status = models.IntegerField()
    vugd_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    vugd_end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vugd_detail'
        app_label = 'main'


class VugdocVugDocs(models.Model):
    onjects = None
    vugdoc_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vugdoc_vug_uid = models.ForeignKey(VugVirtualUserGroup, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vugdoc_vug_uid')
    vugdoc_doc_uid = models.ForeignKey(DocDocuments, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vugdoc_doc_uid')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vugdoc_vug_docs'
        app_label = 'main'


class DocdDetail(models.Model):
    objects = None
    docd_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    docd_doc_uid = models.ForeignKey(DocDocuments, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='docd_doc_uid')
    docd_filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    docd_media_url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    docd_status = models.IntegerField()
    docd_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    docd_end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'docd_detail'
        app_label = 'main'

     
class DoctType(models.Model):
    objects = None
    doct_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doct_vug_uid = models.ForeignKey('VugVirtualUserGroup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doct_vug_uid')
    doct_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    doct_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    doct_end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doct_type'
        app_label = 'main'         


class DocDocuments(models.Model):
    object = None
    doc_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doc_doct_uid = models.ForeignKey('DoctType', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doc_doct_uid')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doc_documents'
        app_label = 'main'
```

As one can see the actual query is not so complicated.
The goal here is just to get the list of valid(active, not deleted) files avilable for a specific VUG(Simple user group), if the group has a valid status.
So if there is any Django ORM experts who can help with what is really a common SQL type that should be should be possible to be converted to a Django ORM script, your help will sincerely be appreciated.

Comment: What does `objects = None` on all the models do ?

Comment: Nothing. It can be removed.

Comment: @MichaelLindsay: normally the idea is to remove the `.objects` manager.

Comment: Django's default ORM manager is accessed though `MODELNAME.objects` so, `objects = None`  would remove access to it.

Comment: I have tested it with and without objects = None and it works both ways. Do you perhaps have advice to my question above?

Comment: I have edited the SQL. Was missing one table name. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The Django way to query multiple related tables is to chain them using dot notation.

A sudo code example might help point you in the right direction.

```
vug_virtual_user_group = VugVirtualUserGroup.objects.get(vug_uid="Some ID")
print(f'vug_virtual_user_group {vug_virtual_user_group}')
```

A lookup using the foreign key to get all related objects

```
vugdoc_vugdocs = vug_virtual_user_group.vugdocvugdocs_set.all()
print(f'vugdoc_vugdocs {vugdoc_vugdocs}')
```

This example assumes that the default modelmanger `objects` is not overridden by `objects = None`.